# A member of the type, 'aim1_Accuracy', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm connecting my asp.net mvc project with my sql server database but when I add the last column it says:

The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'AIRDMIS.Models.R1T_CDC'. A member of the type, 'aim1_Accuracy', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name
only one column is not working the rest shows fine

my code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace AIRDMIS.Models
{
     [Table("R1T_CDC")]
    public class R1T_CDC
    {
        [Key]
        public string Meta_instanceID { get; set; }
        public double? S_No { get; set; }
        public DateTime? SubmissionDate { get; set; }
        public double? aim1_Latitude { get; set; }
        public double? aim1_Longitude { get; set; }
        public double? aim1_Altitude { get; set; }
        [Column("[aim1-Accuracy]")]
        public double? aim1_Accuracy { get; set; }
    }
}
```

```
    public class Context : DbContext
    {
        public Context() : base("DefaultConnection") { }
        public DbSet<R1T_CDC> R1T_CDC { get; set; }
    }
}
```

my Controller

```
        public ActionResult About()
        {
            var data = db.Database.SqlQuery<R1T_CDC>(@"select * from R1T_CDC");
            return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think you need to remove this annotation : '[Column("[aim1-Accuracy]")]' or change it with '[Column("[aim1_Accuracy]")]'

Comment: still same error

Comment: have you created and applied the migration?

Comment: the first 6 columns works just fine but when i add last column it gives error

Comment: Not sure since I haven't used the Column attribute yet, but maybe you need to get rid of the brackets? Sure, you need them in Query Manager because of the hyphen but here you explicitely denote that it is a Column name, so I doubt you need  them here.

Comment: still same error without the brackets.It's also my first time that I'm using Column attribute. I use it because my column name have "-" singe in between

Comment: Is this code-first and happens during initial migration or is it at a later stage?

Comment: it is at a later stage

Comment: Thought so. Well then show what exactly you are doing. The error is triggered somewhere else. Show that code please. Also check the column name in your DB to make sure you don't have a simple typo.

Comment: I edited my question added all the code and pictures please check

Comment: I found something that suggests it might be caused by the edmx file (or missing edmx): https://entityframework.net/knowledge-base/30468336/a-member-of-the-type---propertyname---does-not-have-a-corresponding-column-in-the-data-reader-with-the-same-name  and  https://entityframework.net/knowledge-base/25553596/the-data-reader-is-incompatible-with-the-specified-class

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the problem might be, but I might try Enumerating your select objects in the SQL Query. If you enumerate the field and then get an error that the field does not exist on the table, that would indicate the error is with the database table.

```
var data = db.Database.SqlQuery<R1T_CDC>(@"select S_No, SubmissionDate, aim1_Latitude, aim1_longitude, aim1_altitude, [aim1-Accuracy] from R1T_CDC");
```

(Also, why does the aim1-Accuracy column have brackets around its name in your database table?). Can you get rid of the brackets to see if you still get the error?